# How can i specify the size of the size of an expression in Antlr4?

Tags: java, grammar, antlr4

I am trying to set the size of the expression in the antlr4 grammar file

I tried some different ways of getting the size, since i need to restrict the size of my 
expression

I need to throw an error if my expression is having more than a 7 integer/decimal value.

1) `weight  :  {match(FLOAT);   if(_localctx.getText().length()>7){notifyErrorListeners("above 7 count value");}} ;`

```
FLOAT : ('0'..'9')* '.' ('0'..'9')+ ;
```

2) `(a+=NUMERIC* b+=DECIMAL* c+=NUMERIC+)+  {$a.size()+$b.size()+$c.size() <= 7 && $b.size()<=1}?<fail={"Exceeded weight value"}>`

```
NUMERIC : [0-9];
DECIMAL  : '.';
```

I am searching for an optimal solution

Please advise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should parse your input using the most relaxed grammar possible for your language. For example, if an integer is only allowed to have 6 digits, you should still create your `Integer` token with a rule like the following:

```
Integer
  : [0-9]+
  ;
```

The lexer and parser would not contain any validation that the integer was less than or equal to 6 characters. After the parsing is complete and you have a parse tree, use one or more listeners and/or visitors to perform all validation of your various semantic requirements.

This strategy has a **dramatic** positive impact on the ability of the parser and validator to report understandable error messages to users, so much so that it *vastly* outweighs any perceived advantage of placing the validation code within the grammar itself.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that the "relaxed" parser may not result in a different parse, e.g. if an integer is made of 1-6 digits and 12 digits in succession should be parsed as two 6 digit integers. At least it should parse all correct input as expected and it should be easy to detect the parts that we're only accepted since the parser is not as strict as possible.